# Elasticsearch data-stream selecting indices to search

Tags: elasticsearch

with our current implementation of search engine we do something like:

- search by date range `from` `to` (by `@timestamp`)
- get all indices by some prefix (e.g. `technical-logs*`)
- filter out only those indices which applies the range `from` `to` (e.g. if `from=20230101` and `to=20230118` then we select all indices in those ranges with prefix `technical-logs-yyyyMMdd`)

It seems like that data streams could be beneficial for us. The problem I see is that all indices being created by data streams are hidden by default so I won't be able to see them (by default) therefore I won't be able to query only those indices which I'm interested in (from-to).
Is there some easy mechanism how we can select only indices which we want or does the ES has some functionality for that? I know that there is `@timestamp` field but I don't know if that is somehow being used also to filtering out only indices which contains given date.

Answer (score 1):

That's the whole point of time series data streams, i.e. you don't need to know which indices to query, you just query the data stream (i.e. like an alias) or a subset thereof `technical-logs*` and ES will make sure to only query the underlying indexes that satisfy your constraints (from/to time interval, etc)

Time-series data streams use [time bound indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tsds.html#time-bound-indices). Each of those backing indices is then [sorted by `@timestamp`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tsds.html#tsds-index-sorting) so that when you search for a specific time interval, ES will only query the relevant backing indexes.

Comment: To be clear, from what I see, if you query a datastream (not a TSDS datastream) with 'filter { @timestamp: [A to B]}' and it has 4 backing indices, only one of which has values in [A to B], ES will still query all 4 indices. Your first paragraph makes it sound otherwise.

Comment: @Persimmonium If you look at the second paragraph, I'm specifically talking about TSDS. I'll make it clearer